# How can i download multiple image together with rxAndroid and get an individual callback in OnNext method

Tags: java, android, rx-android

I want to download multiple images together ( in different thread ) and want to get an individual callback for each image download complete ( in onNext method).

but from this code image are download one by one and take a lot of time.
if this not possible from rxAndroid. then how can I do this.?

```
public void downloadImages(Observer<String> ob){
    getUrlObservable(imageUrls).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(ob);
}

private Observable<String> getUrlObservable(List<String> imageUrls) {

    return getEachUrl(imageUrls).flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
            return saveImageForProduct(s);
        }
    });

}


private Observable<String> getEachUrl(List<String> imageUrls){
    return Observable.fromArray(imageUrls).flatMapIterable(new Function<List<String>, Iterable<? extends String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<? extends String> apply(List<String> imageurls) throws Exception {
            return imageUrls;
        }
    });

}



   private Observable<String> saveImageForProduct(final String imageUrl) {

    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
            FileDownloader.downloadFile(imageUrl, Constants.getFileName(imageUrl) + ".jpg");
            emitter.onNext(imageUrl);
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    }).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(""));

}
```

i am getting like this in response--

```
I/Thread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
I/next:https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files1.jpg
I/Thread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
I/next:https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files1.jpg
```

I want to get like this--

```
I/Thread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
I/Thread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
I/next:https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files1.jpg
I/next:https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list containing the download urls and use `flatMap` for achieving that.

```
Observable
.from(imageList)
.flatMap(listItem -> 
    Observable
        .from(listItem)
        .doOnNext(item -> downloadImage(listItem.imageUrl))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.doOnError(t -> logError(t))
.subscribe();
```